# Showing progress in command-line application

Tags: c++, c

Ok, I am a bit embarrassed to ask such a simple thing but still.

I have command line utility application and need to show progress to the user.

I could write progress into cout, like this:

```
std::cout << "10%\n";
...
std::cout << "20%\n";
...
std::cout << "30%\n";
```

... but as a result user will see:

```
some line printed before
10%
20%
30%
...
```

... but what i really need is that percentage got **updated**, like this at the beginning:

```
some line printed before
10%
...
```

... and after update:

```
some line printed before
20%
...
```

... and after second update:

```
some line printed before
30%
...
```

How should I achieve that?

Comment: Although the answers below are good, it is impossible to say for certain what will work, unless you state the operating system your program runs in.

Comment: @AmigableClarkKant I need that work both on Linux(Ubuntu) and Windows.

Comment: I think Joachim Pileborgs answer should work fine for these.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Instead of using `'\n'`, use `'\r'`:

```
std::cout << "\r10%" << std::flush;
```

Print newline (`'\n'`) when done.

It's important to use `std::flush` so the stream contents really is output.

Answer (score 6):

Use a **carriage return**.

```
std::cout << "\r10%";
std::cout << "\r20%";
...
```

Goes to the beginning of the line.